# How to define a object type in a function?

Tags: flowtype

I always get this error:

> Cannot reference type details_T [1] from a value position.

Here is my code:

```
type details_T = {
    code: string, desc: string,    
}

export default {
    data: function () {
        return {
            details: details_T =  { code : 'c', desc : 'd'}
        };
    },

    msg : function() {
        var s : string = 'tset'
        s = 100
        console.log('test')
    }

};
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing object initialization with type annotations. If you want to annotate function's return type you can go with:

```
data: function (): { details: details_T  } {
    return {
        details: { code : 'c', desc : 'd'}
    };
},
```

Comment: if it is ok to return { details : {}} too, how to add that? details?: seems not working

Comment: You can make properties optional `code?: string, desc?: string,` or use union type `function (): { details: details_T | {}  }`. Choose what works best for your scenario